# em editor shortcut or macro or command to remove or erase filter toolbar history

Tags: emeditor

what is the shortcut or command in em editor for clearing or erasing filter history ?
i didn't find it in help manual. can you give java command for clearing or erasing
all filter history?
i have come across a command to remove only last item document.Filter("", 0, eeFindRemoveLast);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **Customize** dialog box, select the **History** page, click the **Clear History...** button, set the **Recent filters** option, and click **OK**.  There is no macro command to clear the Filter history. However, you could delete `%APPDATA%\Emurasoft\EmEditor\Common` to clear the Filter history while EmEditor is not running.

[image: EmEditor - Clear Filter History]